# lookupcache.LookupCachePolicy.cachehit shows either true or false across request

Tags: apigee

So I have an API endpoint that creates a Cache and validate if that cache exist. However the Lookup Cache policy shows different responses across repeated request of the same payload. It would show either true or false across multiple request. Why is this so?.

[image]

The Flow variables lookupcache.LookupCachePolicy.cachekey & lookupcache.LookupCachePolicy.cachename are the same across all this request anyway but still the cachehit value would either be true or false even though the value exist in the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution for me was removing

```
<PurgeChildEntries>true</PurgeChildEntries>
```

in my Invalidate Cache Policy as for some reason it randomly invalidates caches that is not inputted in the reference of a  property. Hence the intermittent response being receive in the Lookup Cache Policy.

[See this link for further details](https://community.apigee.com/questions/78168/lookupcachelookupcachepolicycachehit-shows-either.html?childToView=78472#answer-78472)